# How to get the element connectivity table in abaqus CAE (version 14)?

Tags: output, element, connectivity, abaqus

I am modelling a space frame in Abaqus. I need to take elements that satisfy certain criteria in the model (vertical, at certain angles, height less than) and then calculate the strains on them. I know how to export the field outputs (for U1, U2 and U3, etc) for the whole model. It would be great if I could get the node table (with undeformed node coordinates) and element connectivity table for the whole model. Is there a way to export these tables in a text file (or some other file) so that I can do the post processing outside Abaqus (preferably in MATLAB)?

Comment: you have the connectivity in your input file already?

Comment: Thank You! That was excatly what I was looking for.